# label and title is missing in option tag created with smarty v3

Tags: php, html, smarty3, smarty2

I have searched everywhere for it and didn't find any solution for it.
The problem is "label" and "title" attributes are missing from < option > tag created with {html_options} (html generated with latest smarty_v3)

> {html_options values=$ipList output=$ipList selected=$special_note.ip}

output:

```
<option value="192.168.1.10">192.168.1.10</option>
<option value="192.168.1.10">192.168.1.10</option>
```

whereas in older version (smarty_v2*) it displays both the attributes in < option > tag

output:

```
<option label="192.168.1.10" value="192.168.1.10" title="192.168.1.10">192.168.1.10</option>
<option label="192.168.1.110" value="192.168.1.110" title="192.168.1.110">192.168.1.110</option>
```

Currently i am upgrading code base and db to latest including (smarty, mysqli and apache). I am looking for solution, so that i can handle it globally or else i have to write {foreach} loop for every {html_option}

Comment: May I ask *why* you need these attributes in the first place?

Comment: I have strict instruction "what is there in older code version, must be available in latest ".. I am upgrading codebase to latest. I have made changes for deprecated function and other related stuff  :(

Answer (score 1):

According to the current documentation `html_options` seems not to set those attributes anymore (http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.options.tpl).